# Permutation of pi in a cycle

Tags: permutations, cyclic-groups

In how many permutations $\pi$ of ${1, 2, 3 · · ·, n}$ ($n ≥ 3$) do the
elements $1$, $2$, $3$ are not all in the same cycle?

Comment: Hi, welcome. What have you tried?

Comment: What does "permutations of $\pi$" even *mean*?  Could you show just one?

Comment: Have you tried counting the permutation in which $1,2,3$ are in the same cycle?